# How to make oracle table as a source for Spark Streaming?

Tags: oracle, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Hi have a scenario where I need to capture realtime row-inserts in Oracle table using Spark-Streaming, structured streaming.
One option is to write the Oracle rows to kafka topic, and make kafka topic as source for Spark. But my business Client does not want to post anything in Kafka.
So is at all possible to capture the realtime data insert in Oracle table using Spark Streaming?... i.e. make Oracle as source for Spark Streaming?

Comment: I‘m not familiar with `Spark Streaming`,but you can use `CDC` technology to capture the realtime data inserted into Oracle table and send data to `Spark`,Debezium is the open source solution.

Comment: there is a solution based on Oracle Golden Gate replication plus Kafka Connect https://www.confluent.io/blog/streaming-data-oracle-using-oracle-goldengate-kafka-connect/